# browsing javascript

Tags: java, javascript, swing, browser, jeditorpane

I want to write a simple web browser in java and here’s my code!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

 public class WebBrowser extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JPanel
    address_panel, window_panel;

public JLabel
    address_label;

public JTextField
    address_tf;

public JEditorPane
    window_pane;

public JScrollPane
    window_scroll;

public JButton
    address_b;

private Go go = new Go();

public WebBrowser() throws IOException {

    // Define address bar
    address_label = new JLabel(" address: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    address_tf = new JTextField("http://www.yahoo.com");
    address_tf.addActionListener(go);
    address_b = new JButton("Go");
    address_b.addActionListener(go);

    window_pane = new JEditorPane("http://www.yahoo.com");
    window_pane.setContentType("text/html");
    window_pane.setEditable(false);

    address_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    window_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    address_panel.add(address_label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    address_panel.add(address_tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    address_panel.add(address_b, BorderLayout.EAST);

    window_scroll = new JScrollPane(window_pane);
    window_panel.add(window_scroll);

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    pane.add(address_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(window_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setTitle("web browser");
    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public class Go implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        try {

            window_pane.setPage(address_tf.getText());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {     // new URL() failed
            window_pane.setText("MalformedURLException: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {               // openConnection() failed
            window_pane.setText("IOException: " + e);
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
}

}
```

It works fine for simple html pages but it cannot load JavaScript part of the code! My problem is what should I add to the code to load the javascripts? Thank you!

Comment: You'd need some sort of Javascript engine placed into your browser.  You could write your own, or look around and see if anyone's ported one to Java.

Comment: *"I want to write a simple web browser"*  I want to catch Dodos for my Petting Farm.  Given there are no Dodos and no 'simple web browsers', we've both got our work cut out.  ;)

Comment: will you please explain more?

Comment: @Makoto  I think you got a comment.  :)

Comment: @MooshiBlack  In case that comment was directed at me.  I note `new JEditorPane("http://www.yahoo.com");`.  A `JEditorPane` is ***not*** suitable for displaying HTML from the World Wild Web.  By the time you put enough work into it that it was, it would have been simpler to write your own class extending `JTextComponent`.

Comment: thank YOU @AndrewThompson! i just copy pasted it from somewhere ,but i don't think that would solve the problem!

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share their reason?  IMWTK.

Comment: i know this a very simple and stupid question!but im a beginner!

Comment: What you are doing now has little chance of succeeding either.  If it does, I'd rush out and buy a lottery ticket, to see if I can translate the 'lucky streak' into cash.

Comment: @MooshiBlack  Even if it is a simple & stupid question (I'm not convinced it is), neither of those is valid grounds for down-voting.

Comment: @AndrewThompson any hints about extending textComponent? How should I get it recognize HTML (what is the best way)?

Comment: *"any hints about extending textComponent?"*  1) Put together a team of coders the approximate size of those which developed Netscape or Chrome 2) ..

Comment: @MooshiBlack:  [Here's a partial list of JavaScript engines that are in use now.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine#JavaScript_engines)  If you want to be able to parse JScript, you would want to either a) see if they have a license flexible enough to allow inclusion in your code and include it, or b) determine how to create one and write that in Java.  B is a bit harder, since that requires more knowledge of both Java *and* Javascript...and you'll of course want the engine to be fast.

Comment: @MooshiBlack - I have been programming in Java since about 1997.  It's what I do every day for a job.  But I wouldn't try to sit down and write a web browser; it's too complex, and too hard to get everything right.  You've said you're a beginner - if you want to learn Java, then maybe you could start with a slightly less ambitious project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing's default widgets only have very basic support for HTML4 and CSS, with absolutely no support for JavaScript at all (by default). You could potentially use the built-in Rhino JavaScript engine to execute the code, but that would have to be done manually and would be pretty difficult. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) uses this tactic to parse HTML pages and execute the JavaScript, but it has generally poor compatibility and completely lacks a renderer, so you'd have to write that yourself (i.e. no display, you only get access to the page content from code).

There's a few Swing-based browser widgets floating around which embed a Gecko (Firefox) or WebKit (Chrome/Safari) renderer and would thus be able to take advantage of proper JavaScript interpreters, but they're all buggy, expensive, or unmaintained. These would all support JavaScript but they generally use very old versions of the various browser engines and have poor compatibility with modern websites, in addition to lacking cross-platform compatibility.

Eclipse's [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) project includes a browser widget that appears to be actively maintained, but has a dependence on the SWT libraries and would be somewhat more difficult to use in a Swing application, though it may be possible. SWT is an entirely different UI toolkit from AWT/Swing (which you're currently using) and in order to take advantage of its browser widget, you'd have to find a way to embed it in a Swing app, or use only the SWT toolkit.

Overall, SWT's browser is probably your best bet for getting a decent browser in Java, but it may still be troublesome to use. Good luck!

Comment: *"Swing's default widgets only have very basic support for HTML4 .."*  HTML 3.2.

Comment: Ouch, even better. It's a shame all the effort toward including a decent browser widget only ever made it into JavaFX, I would've loved to see that in the standard libs...